# Negative infinity and negative zero in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

This is more of a general understanding question

```
a = np.array([-0, 5, 0]).astype(float)
b = 1 / a
print b
```

returns `[ inf  0.2  inf]`

But

```
a = np.array([-0.0, 5, 0])
b = 1 / a
print b
```

returns `[-inf  0.2  inf]`

I expected the first one to return `-inf` for the first element as well, why doesn't it?

Comment: `-0` is an integer, and is identical in all respects to `0` (indeed, it's even the same *object* as `0`, in the sense that `-0 is 0` is `True`, in a normal CPython implementation where small integers are cached). In contrast to floats, there's no such thing as a negative zero for integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integers on most machines have no concept of negative zero, so `-0` is just `0`. Since you build your array from integers before the cast to float, you get `[0.0, 5, 0.0]`.

```
In [2]: np.array([-0, 5, 0]).astype(float)
Out[2]: array([ 0.,  5.,  0.])
```